# Trigger AWS Lambda function whenever a file is added to AWS FSX

Tags: aws-lambda, eventtrigger, aws-event-bridge, amazon-cloudtrail, amazon-fsx

I would like to trigger an AWS Lambda Function whenever a new file is added to AWS FSX. This is in order to perform an action on the file using to the Lambda function that gets notified.

While considering AWS cloudtrail, Eventbridge and Cloudwatch to trigger the Lambda function; I was unable to find AWS FSX in the data source options for this monitoring resource in AWS. Any suggestion on what tool can be used?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/creating_alarms.html

Comment: @JatinMehrotra alarms aren't a solution here. May be worth investigating [File access auditing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/fsx/latest/WindowsGuide/file-access-auditing.html) for file creation events, but I'm not sure of the latency.

Comment: cloudwatch log can be used in this case to trigger the Lambda function.

Comment: @Taiwotman: Did you get a soluton for this?